# Why does it give 'docker' error when running running Import-TestToolkitToNavContainer?

Tags: powershell, azure-container-service, dynamics-business-central

I run the following from Powershell to install TestToolkit to a container in Azure

```
  Import-TestToolkitToNavContainer -containerName <BC CONTAINER NAME IN AZURE>
```

But i get the error

```
   "Import-TestToolkitToNavContainer : The term 'docker' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, 
   function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was 
   included, verify that the path is correct and try again."
```

Any ideas ? Do i need to install a module ?

**Update:**
Its an Azure Container.. But in the meantime I have run up a Azure VM running docker. I can login to Business Central on the VM , which is a step closer than the container. But how can i get back the metadata , in Postman I am using ?
I have tried the following:

```
     http://Server:OdataServicePort/ServiceName/api/beta/$metadata

     Server = WebClient 
     OdataServicePort: ?? is it 7748 or can i retrieve it
     ServiceName:  SandBox <--is that correct or can i retrieve this as well
```

I am using Basic Auth with the User in BC and the web access key .

Is this the correct way to retrieve the metadata ?

Comment: Are you using BcContainerHelper or NavContainerHelper?

Comment: sorry typo....i thought you can import into an existing container using Import-TestToolkitToBCContainer -name <CONTAINER NAME IN AZURE>

Comment: When you say "container in Azure" is it an Azure Container or an Azure VM running docker?

Comment: I have update the question

Answer (score 0):

You should start by running `Get-BcContainerServerConfiguration` from PowerShell.

From the result of this command you can then build the correct URL:

```
http://[ContainerName]:[ODataServicesPort]/[ServerInstance]/api/v1.0
```

Note: If you enable SSL when creating the container, you need to use `https` instead og `http`.

Comment: I keep getting the error:      Invoke-ScriptInBcContainer : The term 'docker' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, 
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name,